# Handler for app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I have the following code in my electron client.

```js
    console.log(app.isDefaultProtocolClient("modbotclient"));
    console.log(app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("modbotclient"));

    protocol.registerHttpProtocol("modbotclient", (request, callback) => {
        let url = request.url.substr(15);

        console.log(url);

        callback({
            url
        });
    });
```

When I run **xdg-open modbotcient://test** (I am on ubuntu) my electron application opens but the url is not logged. How do i get the url for processing?